# AddField an array of object using Aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Supposedly I want to get a an object from my collection, an to this object, I want to add a property that will store an array of object containing ids and title matching one of the property of my object (in my case series).

Example I have this object as a result from my initial query

```
{
   _id: 13123123123,
   title: "TitleofObject",
   series: "SeriesName",
}
```

then I want to look on the same collection where the series name is the same for my object (add a new property named sameSeries to store objects matching the series) and the final result of object should look something like this

```
    _id: 13123123123,
   title: "TitleofObject",
   series: "SeriesName",
   sameSeries: 
    [
      {
      _id: 12312312,
      title: "anothertitleofObject"
      }, 
      {
      _id: 12312342312,
      title: "anothertitleofObject2"
      }
    ]
```

How can I achieve this using the aggregate method?

```
 const book = await Book.aggregate([
       {
            $match: { _id: id }
       },
])
```

Comment: Where do you want look like that? In the collection or after aggregation? And where do you have the array elements which should be part of sameSeries array.

Comment: Hello @Gibbs I want to make it a part of aggregation result only and send them as a json object, and the array of objects are also objects from the same collection that match the series of the initial object, So its like im storing those object inside the initial object that I found with id,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": { //Group by series
      "_id": "$series",
      "sameSeries": { //Create an object
        $push: { //push the required fields
          "title": "$title",
          "_id": "$_id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3Oy1d5KZTA8)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": 13123123123,
      "sameSeries": {
        "$exists": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "series",
      "foreignField": "series",
      "as": "sameSeries"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cf7G2djFc7C)

To skip the parent id, you can do a slice

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": 13123123123,
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "series",
      "foreignField": "series",
      "as": "sameSeries"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1,
      series: 1,
      title: 1,
      sameSeries: {
        "$slice": [
          "$sameSeries",
          -1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7xo_AykSHu8)

Comment: Hello, is there any way like to append only the sameseries properties instead of creating a new object, i want to append it only on the initial object that im looking for with id, then append the same series properties if its series is not empty and look for other objects that have the same series and add it to the sameseries

Comment: Check the edit and let me know

Comment: Hello i want to lookup only if series is not empty, I dont want it to be on match method since I still need to get that object regardless if the series is empty or not

Comment: Explain with a sample? What do you mean by non empty series?

Comment: The aggregate function should not add the sameseries array if the series is empty ,something like that sir.

Comment: Check the edited answer

Comment: still not quite right to me , your 2nd answer is almost correct, i just need to do a conditional lookup , if the initial object has a series property that is null or empty,(the properties of objects are _id, title, and series, there are times when series is empty so we dont need to find other objects that has the same series value) dont perform lookup else perform lookup, something like that, is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: I think you can achieve with either `filter` or `unwind, match, group`